# How does one detect whether one is in the preamble or not?

Tags: conditionals, programming, preamble

> In LaTeX, I'd like to know whether a documentclass has been loaded and whether code is inside a `\begin{document}`.  In other words, is there a **`\ifpreamble`** similar to `\ifvmode` and friends?

Partially this is curiosity, partly this is to make it easy to compile a figure as a standalone or included in some larger document.  In the past I've made the including document define a macro, and the figure tests for it, but it'd be nice if the figure could figure it out itself.

Things that don't work (because they aren't changed by `\documentclass` or `\begin{document}`):

- `\ifvmode` is true immediately
- `\@currenvir` is "document" immediately
- `\normalsize` is defined immediately

Answer (score 32, accepted):

LaTeX defines a lot of macros which are only supposed to be used in the preamble of a document (such as `\usepackage`, but also some internal kernel macros). It does this via `\@onlypreamble\SomeMacro`. This works by adding `\SomeMacro` to a list, which at `\begin{document}` are all set equal to `\@notprerr`, which is a macro that generates an error. In particular, the kernel declares `\@onlypreamble\@onlypreamble`. This means that we can test if we are in the preamble by doing

```
\ifx\@onlypreamble\@notprerr (document)\else (preamble)\fi
```

If we're in a package and would like to know if we are loaded before or after the `\documentclass` declaration, we can look at what `\documentclass` does: Among lots of other things, it says `\let\documentclass\@twoclasseserror` (which prevents invoking `\documentclass` twice). So testing if `\documentclass` is ifx-equal to `\@twoclasseserror` takes care of this.

```
\makeatletter
\def\MakeTest#1{%
  \edef#1{%
  \ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror % after \documentclass
    \ifx\@onlypreamble\@notprerr % after \begin{document}
      Hello
    \else % before \begin{document}
      Howdy
    \fi
  \else % before \documentclass
    Hi!
  \fi}}
\makeatother
\MakeTest\foo

\documentclass{minimal}

\MakeTest\bar

\begin{document}
\MakeTest\baz

foo says \foo; bar says \bar; baz says \baz
\end{document}
```

I think this is pretty robust; I don't think any packages change `\documentclass` or `\@onlypreamble` after they have been changed to their error-giving meanings.

[etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) adds `\AfterEndPreamble`. Code in `\AfterEndPreamble{...}` will be detected as  "after `\begin{document}`" (as pointed out by [Ahmed Musa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/994/ahmed-musa) in the comments).

On the one hand per definitionem `\AfterEndPreamble` code is after `\begin{document}`, see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf:

> `\AtEndPreamble` code is part of the preamble; `\AfterEndPreamble`
> code is part of the document body and may contain printable text to be
> typeset at the very beginning of the document. To sum that up, LaTeX
> will perform the following tasks ‘inside’ `\begin{document}`:
>
> - Execute any `\AtEndPreamble` code
> - Start initialization for document body (page layout, default fonts, etc.)
> - Load the main aux file written on the previous LaTeX pass
> - Open the main aux file for writing on the current pass
> - Continue initialization for document body
> - Execute any `\AtBeginDocument` code
> - Complete initialization for document body
> - Disable all `\@onlypreamble` commands
> - Execute any `\AfterEndPreamble` code

On the other hand it is still executed before any of the code typed after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the neat technique.  I was trying to use **\ifx\document{the actual error message all written out}** which was awful. \@notprerr was perfect.  I very much like your test document.  I had one very similar for ifvvmode and friends, but all it said was "foo says Hi; bar says Hi; baz says Hi" which was getting very frustrating.

Comment: In view of, e.g., *etoolbox*'s `\AfterEndPreamble`, this doesn't seem 'pretty robust'. When some code is hooked to the end of `\document`, `\let\@onlypreamble=\@notprerr` doesn't signify the end of `\begin{document}`.

Comment: this does not work anymore :( it get's detected as preamble (goes in else) even after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, to anyone trying this out, `\ifx\@onlypreamble\@notprerr (document)\else (preamble)\fi` doesn't work alone, you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` for those checks to work

Answer (score 10):

If *all* you need this for is to allow you to compile component files separately from the master document, then you might look at [Martin Scharrer's `standalone` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone/), designed to do just that.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like a nice polished solution.  I enjoy cobbling things together, but when I actually need the results to be dependable, I'll use the package.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: My feelings exactly. Sometimes it's a great learning experience to take an answer like @Villemoes' and adapt it to one's exact needs; sometimes "life's too short" and a regular old hammer out' the toolbox is what you need.