# \renewcommand only in subordinated file with subfiles package

Tags: subfiles

Is there a way to renew a command only when the child file is compiled with the `subfiles`-package?

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
  \foo % always returns foo
  \subfile{content}
\end{document}
```

`content.tex`:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\renewcommand{\foo}{bar}

\begin{document}
  Here is some content.
  \foo % always returns bar
\end{document}
```

When I compile `main.tex` the `\foo` called from inside `content.tex` returns bar. I want it to return foo when I compile `main.tex` and bar when I compile `content.tex`. Is this possible?

The documentation for `subfiles`, section 2.2, state that:

> • If the subordinated file was `\subfile`’d, it ignores everything before and
>   including `\begin{document}`, and the ignores `\end{document}` too. (The
>   body of the file, nothing else, is effectively `\input`.)

This does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It could be possible by using a `\if...` statement...I'll take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a internal feature of the `subfiles` class (see doc please)

The class defines `\old@document@subfiles`. If this is present, it is the class running, otherwise the package only. It is quite easy to check for the definition using `etoolbox` `\ifdef{}` and then define the commands accordingly.

[image]

(The screen shot is taken from the documentation subfiles.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{subfiles}%


\makeatletter
\ifdef{\old@document@subfiles}{%
  \newcommand{\foo}{bar}%
}{%
 \newcommand{\foo}{foo}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \foo % always returns foo
  \subfile{content}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works as intended.
A warning to others: This is a hack and could easily break if `subfiles` is updated.

Comment: @neic: Of course it is a hack, as the request involved a feature not designed in the package ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I use `subfiles` and `todonotes` and wanted to have a TOC and a listoftodos also seperately for each subfile when compiled for itself, but only one when compiled from the master file. With your trick I simply defined a `\subfileonly` command in the preamble of the main document (which expands to `\listoftodos \tableofcontents` instead of "bar" and is empty instead of "foo" in my case) and placed `\subfileonly` after `\begin{document}` in each of the subfiles. Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 1):

A sketch, with the assumption, that you know, if `subfiles` is used and you mark this by `\subfilestrue`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newif\ifsubfiles

\newcommand{\foo}{FOO}

\foo
\renewcommand{\foo}{\ifsubfiles BAR\else FOO\fi}

A \foo

\subfilestrue

B \foo

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you are in the preamble or in the actual text using `\ifx\@onlypreamble\@notprerr#1\else#2\fi` as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16298/22187).
Adjusted to your case:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insubfile}[1]{\ifx\@onlypreamble\@notprerr\else#1\fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
\foo % always returns foo
\subfile{content}
\end{document}
```

content.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\insubfile{\renewcommand{\foo}{bar}}

\begin{document}
  Here is some content.
  \foo % always returns bar
\end{document}
```

This gives the desired result and does not depend on internal macros of the `subfiles` package.