# Compilation of main document, if subdocuments are compiled

Tags: compiling, conditionals, external-files

I have a main latex document, and many other files included with `\input{...}`, e.g. by chapter.

Often, I just work on a subfile and my idea is now, that I want to compile the main document if I start the compilation of the subfile.

A short example:
main document

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```

subfile.tex

```
\usepackage{automatic_mainfile_compilation}
some text...
```

So I imagine the following (in pseudo-code) to be in automatic_mainfile_compilation.sty

```
if code == NOT inserted vie \input
  \write18{pdflatex main_document}
  stop compilation with return value of line before 
end

rest of subdocument
```

[Stopping dependent on the called compilation process shouldn't be a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251572/get-return-value-of-write18), but can I somehow recognize during compilation, if I am in an 'inputted' file, and the skip some `wirte18{pdflatex...}`-command?

Comment: Erh, isn't that more a job of the editor? Most editors these days support the concept of a master document to be compiled whenever you ask to compile, regardless of which subfile you are in

Comment: Yes, but if I change the editor, this would also work...

Comment: All editors are different. I would not like to receive a file that suddenly starts compiling it self. I would not recommend spending more time on this.

Comment: That's my point, all editors are different ;) So my approach could work with any editor... I just would make a sty-file, which is included in all subfiles.

Comment: You can't use `\usepackage` after `\begin{document}`. Beside this: Your method will only work with --shell-escape, which means that you would have to setup your editor to use it. Setting the main file is easier.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need --shell-escape anyway... And recognizing if there has been `\begin{document}` is no problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16298/44467 But maybe this already resolves my problem, because then I don't need to know anymore, if the current file is loaded by `\input` or not...

Comment: Well I wouldn't activate --shell-escape by default. And you don't need to do complicated tests for `\begin{document}`: It is enough to test if \jobname is main. But you will not be able to insert your code with `\usepackage` in the subfiles, you must use `\input`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course you are right, I have to use `\input`... and the test seems to be quite easy now, `\jobname` seems to be the right thing...

Comment: why not use `\include` ?(processing single sections is exactly what `\include` is there to support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is fine for me now:

```
\def\myjobb{main} % name of main tex file
\edef\myjob{\meaning\myjobb}
\edef\tmpjob{\jobname}
\edef\tmpjob{\meaning\tmpjob}

\ifx\myjob\tmpjob
\else
  \immediate\write18{cd .. && pdflatex --shell-escape \myjobb} % go up one folder, as file is in subfolder for subfiles...
  \immediate\write18{ pidof mupdf-x11 | xargs kill -s SIGHUP} % reload pdf
\stop
\fi
```

---

Or even simpler: When the subfiles are in an subfolder, the different cases can be easily separated by `\input{somefile}` which exists two times, once as an empty file in the folder of the main tex file, and once to start compilation in the subfolder...